# Jquery ajax function and downloading files

Tags: jquery, ajax, download

I am using `$ajax( { type:"post", url:"/whatever/" } )` to access my server which works nicely. The problem is that the response is not evaluated as I need it.
On some occations the server sends back a dummy string ("x") which can be ignored on the browser, but on other occasions my server sends back a special file as attachment:

```
mimetype application/x-my-special-type
Content-Disposition attachment; filename=myname.ext
....
```

But the browser (I am only interested in Google Chrome / Chromium - it's an intranet thing) does not show the download popup window. (Calling the "/whatever/" URL directly in the address bar actually DOES show the download popup window to save the file.)

How can I persuade jQuery to show the usual download popup window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send the user to the URL by setting `window.location.href` or linking directly to the file. Do not use AJAX for this, as it is only used for retrieving data to variables/inserting to DOM. You'll probably need to think of a different way to represent the no-response case. Perhaps the AJAX portion could be used to establish if a file is available or not, and the redirection would occur if the AJAX response indicates that a file is available.

Comment: I was afraid to read that. Seems that I must send the ajax request, check the answer from the server, and if it contains something like "download_waiting" then do the window.location.href to actually do the download :(

Comment: Indeed. Updated my answer to say exactly that as you entered your comment.

Comment: The no response could probably be handled by a 404 page, or a similar "The requested file was not found" type page.